# Issues with making a custom version of Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, browser, webkit

To be completely honest, I am a complete noob at coding so please forget me for my stupidity. I am trying to make a custom version of Firefox. (As in, change looks, and maybe a few other things, but leave the Gecko engine alone, because I would probably break it.) Anyway, exactly how does one do this? (EG: How do I start editing Firefox, how do I save those edits, etc) Should I use something else, like Webkit or Chromium?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is specifically geared towards answering questions about problems you have in code. General questions like "How do I get started?" can usually be answered via Google. You're asking about modifying Firefox source code, so you should first read [their introduction page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction). Once you run into a coding problem, use StackOverflow! Show us what you've tried and what problem it's giving you and we can help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: Alright thank you! That's extremely helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to create a [custom theme](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/use-themes-change-look-of-firefox) for [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox), try this [guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/203803/how-to-create-your-own-firefox-browser-theme/).

Comment: Thank you! Thats a good place to start!

Comment: @TheGhzGuy , can you up vote my answer if it it helped you?

Comment: It tried, but since I literally made this account an hour ago, and I have no reputation, it doesn't show up publicly. Sorry.

Comment: @TheGhzGuy , okay, you need to have at least 15 reputation in order to [vote up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

Comment: I clicked the check marker, I guess that works?